# Not able to access a function of external JS file from TS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have defined a function in external JS file.I am not able to use it in home.page.ts file. It is showing error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionName' of undefined

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="assets/multiLayerSource.js"></script>
</body>
```

**multiLayerSource.js**

```
var multiLayerSource;

var layersHT = [];

function SetLayerHT(arglayersHT) {
    layersHT = arglayersHT;
}
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit, Renderer, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
declare var multiLayerSource: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    layersHTP: any = [];
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.layersHTP.push( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
        multiLayerSource.SetLayerHT(this.layersHTP);
    }
}
```

It is showing error while trying to access SetLayerHT().
The error is :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'SetLayerHT' of undefined.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Move your js file to asset folder then in your code do like this

```
import 'assets/js/multiLayerSource';

declare var SetLayerHT: any;

ngOnInit() {
 this.layersHTP.push( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
 SetLayerHT(this.layersHTP);
}
```